# Kotlin, casting function receiver

Tags: kotlin

I have a couple `object`s, such as `object Buffer`, offering determined functions and I'd like to call

```
binding(bufferName[Buffer.VERTEX] to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER) {
    ... // calling Buffer functions
}
```

where inside I have available, for example, the functions of the `object Buffer` because of the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`

`binding` is at the moment so defined

```
inline fun <T, R> binding(pair: Pair<Int, Int>, block: T.() -> R)
```

So my question is if it's possible "casting" T to a specific object based on pair.second so that I can call those functions that the object offers?

Comment: Doesn't Kotlin force you to specify the function generic types in this case, making the type available in the block body? binding<Buffer,Bar>(..){ //buffer methods available on "this"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing T depending on the Int value `pair.second` is not, to the best of my knowledge, possible. However, sealed classes are a good way to implement this sort of "enum with different methods for each value" kind of logic:

```
sealed class BufferType(val type: Int) {
    class ArrayBuffer() : BufferType(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
    class AtomicCounterBuffer() : BufferType(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER)
    /* other buffer types... */
}

inline fun <Buffer: BufferType, R> binding(pair: Pair<Int,Buffer>, block : (Buffer) -> R) {
    glBindBuffer(pair.second.type, pair.first)
    block()
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you can expose all the available buffer methods on either the top level `BufferType` class (for globally available methods), or each individual buffer type.